# Multiprocessing not working

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have use all types of multiprocessing Pool but still the program only using single core (available=8).Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
 import multiprocessing
 from multiprocessing import Pool

 class pdf_gen():
   def __init__(self):
     pdf = self.pdf = FPDF()
     pdf.set_auto_page_break(True,0.1)

   def get_data_from_mysql(self) :
     pdf = self.pdf
     # connection is established and result is stored in 'res'.
     dup = []
     dup.insert(0,res)
     z = tuple(dup)
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
     pool.apply_async(self.mysql_to_pdf_data,z)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()

   def mysql_to_pdf_data(self,*result) :
     try : 
       pdf = self.pdf 
       # Entered data need to be in pdf
     finally : 
       pdf.output('save_pdf.pdf','F')
```

It takes approximately 20 mins to make pdf but I need it to take upto max 4 minutes.

I have updated my code.

```
 import multiprocessing
 from multiprocessing import Pool

 class pdf_gen():
   def __init__(self):
     pdf = self.pdf = FPDF()
     pdf.set_auto_page_break(True,0.1)

   def get_data_from_mysql(self) :
     pdf = self.pdf
     # connection is established and result is stored in 'res'.
     dup = []
     dup.insert(0,res)
     z = tuple(dup)
     return z

   def mysql_to_pdf_data(self,*result) :
     try : 
       pdf = self.pdf 
       # Entered data need to be in pdf
     finally : 
       pdf.output('save_pdf.pdf','F')

 def main() :
   pdf = pdf_gen()
   recover_data = pdf.get_data_from_mysql()
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
   pool.map(pdf.mysql_to_pdf_data,recover_data)
```

[I have attached the cpu utilisaion it using only 1 core at a particular time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOwk6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply_async` calls **one** function with all the arguments (`z`) and returns a result object that can be called later to wait for the result of the function.

I think you want `map` or `starmap`, which takes either an iterable of single arguments or an iterable of sets of arguments, respectively, and calls the function with each set of arguments in parallel.

Example of `map`.  Note it takes 5 seconds to process the first 8 on my 8-core system, and 5 more seconds to process the next two:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def process(pdf):
    name = mp.current_process().name
    print(name,'got',pdf)
    s = time.time()
    while time.time() - s < 5:  # Spin wait to max CPU utilization
        pass
    return pdf + ' processed'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = [f'pdf{x}' for x in range(1,11)]
    pool = mp.Pool()
    start = time.time()
    print(pool.map(process,args))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('took',time.time() - start,'secs')
```

Output:

```
SpawnPoolWorker-2 got pdf1
SpawnPoolWorker-1 got pdf2
SpawnPoolWorker-3 got pdf3
SpawnPoolWorker-5 got pdf4
SpawnPoolWorker-6 got pdf5
SpawnPoolWorker-4 got pdf6
SpawnPoolWorker-7 got pdf7
SpawnPoolWorker-8 got pdf8
SpawnPoolWorker-1 got pdf9
SpawnPoolWorker-2 got pdf10
['pdf1 processed', 'pdf2 processed', 'pdf3 processed', 'pdf4 processed', 'pdf5 processed', 'pdf6 processed', 'pdf7 processed', 'pdf8 processed', 'pdf9 processed', 'pdf10 processed']
took 10.375263214111328 secs
```

When running the above code, you can see that all the CPUs maxed out during execution:

[image: CPU Utilization Graph]

Comment: I have used map and starmap but they are also using only one core. I am having hard luck finding out the solution for this problem.

Comment: @PuneetSingh Did you try the above code I posted and it only uses one core?  I've updated to show it clearly uses all of them.  Update your question with a similar example if it isn't working for you.

Comment: I have run your code it works perfectly as you had said. Can you make it doable for my project too?

Comment: I have update my code in above section.Can you take a look over there and let me know the problem?

Comment: @PuneetSingh It looks like your code puts *one* item in a list with `get_data_from_mysql`, so that is only one job and will use only one core.  Put a bunch of items in the list like my code does it it should use more cores.