# How to confirm multiprocessing library is being used?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing for the below code. The code seems to run a bit faster than the for loop inside the function.

How can I confirm I using the library and not the just the for loop?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import requests 
import pandas as pd

data= pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/50kNAE000.txt.1' ,sep="\t", header=None)
data = data[0].str.strip("0    ")

lst = []

def request(x):
    for i,v in x.items():
        print(i)
        file = requests.get(v)
        lst.append(file.text)
    #time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    results = pool.map(request(data))
    pool.close()  # 'TERM'
    pool.join()   # 'KILL'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing has overhead.  It has to start the process and transfer function data via interprocess mechanism.  Just running a single function in another process vs. running that same function normally is always going to be slower.  The advantage is actually doing *parallelism* with significant work in the functions that makes the overhead minimal.

You can call `multiprocessing.current_process().name` to see the process name change.

Comment: thanks for the response. So if i understand correctly, it is better to do more steps within my function to get more 'speed' out of multiprocessing?

Comment: @Rusty *Parallel* steps.  If you issued 2 parallel requests, it *might* get done faster, depending on the response time compared to startup overhead.  If issued 20 requests, it *likely* will get done faster.

Comment: could you give me an example in code how I could achieve that?

Comment: @RustyShackleford Search SO for examples.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50594714/235698) is a toy example from one of my previous answers.  Also, note how that example uses the pool.map.  In your code you are calling the function, not passing the name of the function to pool.map.